# Why is the Argument taken as an Object and not as an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Why is the Argument taken as an Object and not as an Array??

---

## Question Description:

Consider an array of sheep where some sheep may be missing from their place. We need a function that counts the number of sheep present in the array (true means present).

For example,

```
 [true,  true,  true,  false,
  true,  true,  true,  true ,
  true,  false, true,  false,
  true,  false, false, true ,
  true,  true,  true,  true ,
  false, false, true,  true]
```

The correct answer would be 17.

---

## My Solution:

```
   function countSheeps(arrayOfSheeps) 
{
    var num=0;
    for(var i=0; i<arrayOfSheeps.lenght(); i++)
     {  
       if(arrayOfSheeps[i]==true){ num=num+1; } 
     }
    return num;
}
```

---

## Test Cases:

```
var array1 = [true,  true,  true,  false,
              true,  true,  true,  true ,
              true,  false, true,  false,
              true,  false, false, true ,
              true,  true,  true,  true ,
              false, false, true,  true ];

Test.expect(countSheeps(array1) == 17, "There are 17 sheeps in total")
```

---

## Output:

```
TypeError: Object true,true,true,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,true,false,true,false,false,true,true,true,true,true,false,false,true,true has no method 'lenght'
   at countSheeps


0 Passed
0 Failed
1 Errors

Process took 110ms to complete
```

P.S. I am a newbie to JS.

Comment: `lenght` is not the same as `length`. Also, it is not a function. So, `arrayOfSheeps.length` is enough.

Comment: Also length is not a function. Just use `length`

Comment: I changed arrayOfSheeps.lenght() to arrayOfSheeps.lenght But now it says Incorrect There are 17 sheeps in total

Comment: what exactly is it saying?

Comment: `lenght` is still not spelled correctly!

Comment: I am really SORRY, please PARDON me I didn't realized that i was misspelling length...;-(

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments you should correct `lenght()` to `length`

```
function countSheeps(arrayOfSheeps) 
{
    var num=0;
    for(var i=0; i<arrayOfSheeps.length; i++)
    {  
      if(arrayOfSheeps[i]==true){ num++; }
    }
    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the Argument taken as an Object and not as an Array??

Because all arrays are objects in javascript. That error message basically contains the type of the reference base (which is an object, as opposed to a primitive type such as string/number/boolean) and the `.toString()` representation of that object (which in the case of your array of booleans just is the same as `arrayOfSheeps.join(',')`).

It does not say that `arrayOfSheeps` wasn't an array. It just says that the array object is an object.

Comment: @SharpEdge: The underlying problem was clearly solved in the comments, I didn't want to bother pointing out typos again. Instead I answered the actual question :-)

Comment: Sure but it's clear that the question is wrong, the user wanted to know why the test failed and supposed that the issue was caused by a wrong casting.
I think that for future readers we should post answers as "answers" and don't left them in the comments area.

Comment: @SharpEdge: I didn't see any evidence that the user did not want to know what he was asking for - both the title and his question were "*Why is the argument an Object not an Array?*", not "*Why does my code not work?*"

Answer (score 0):

public int countSheeps(Boolean[] arrayOfSheeps) {

```
var num=0;

for(var i=0; i<arrayOfSheeps.length; i++)
 {  
   if(arrayOfSheeps[i]!=null && arrayOfSheeps[i]==true){ num=num+1; } 
 } 
return num;
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).